# collect data form array of students grades and loop insert via sql only for students with no data

Tags: php, sql, loops

Hi all just another hurdle to jump.
I have a dynamic list of students from a form

```
<form method="POST" name="assignments" id="assignments" action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<?php
$key = 0;
while($row_students = mysql_fetch_array($students))
{ ?>
<div style="margin-bottom:3px;">
<select name="student[<?php echo $key ?>][grade]" size="1">
  <option value="NULL">--</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="20" selected="selected">20</option>
</select>

<?php echo $row_students['student_number'];?> 
<input name="student[<?php echo $key ?>][student_id]" type="hidden" 
 value="<?php echo $row_students['student_number']; ?>" /> -

<?php echo $row_students['student_name'] ; ?>
<input name="student[<?php echo $key ?>][assignment_name]" type="hidden" 
 value="<?php echo $row_assignments['assignment_name'];?>" />
 </div>
 <br/>
<?php $key++;} ?>
<input name="section" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['section']; ?>" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
| <a href="index.php">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

I then have a sql that loops through and inserts them into the db which works

```
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])){ 

$sql = array(); 
foreach( $_POST['student'] as $row ) { 
$sql[] = '(
         '."NULL".',
         '.mysql_prep($row['grade']).', 
                 '.mysql_prep($row['student_id']).', 
         '."'{$row['assignment_name']}'".',
         '."'{$current_section}'".')
         '; } 

 mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO 
               graded_assignment (id, grade, student_id,    assignment_name, section) 
               VALUES '.implode(',', $sql)); 
confirm_query($sql);                       
if(mysql_affected_rows()>=0)  
{  
    redirect_to("index.php?assignment=1");
}
}
```

Here's the ? if i move a student into another class after the teacher has submitted the grades, he will have data already submitted and the new teacher wont be able to submit the grades because data already exist for one student.

How can i check first if data exist for the student and then only insert where there is no data? the student_id and assignment_name are unique so the combo won't insert.

OR if the student already has data don't echo his name in the student list

Thanks I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you're using MySQL, use

```
INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE
```

(or UPDATE if you want to update instead). However, you need to have a primary key set up in order for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late sign of gratitude. ;)